# Peter Kämpf exceeding level 200,000, might pop up at space.exchange anytime soon!

Tags: discussion

Congratulations to [Peter Kämpf](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/1961/peter-k%C3%A4mpf?tab=profile) on reaching a reputation of 200000!

He is the first to reach this level, and did so shortly before anybody else managed to exceed level 100000.

In six years and 11 month of participating here, Peter contributed 1,814 answers 9 questions and reached approximately 9.1 million people.

In his profile, Peter says:

> You have understood something only if you are able to explain it to
> others. Answering here helps me to understand things better.

We know for sure that Peter understands many things better now, and so do we!

Peter, thank you for all your marvellous contributions to this site!

Comment: I for one, am always shocked to see a Peter Kämpf _question_! Now I know that  this is quantitatively justified. Congrats, Peter!

Comment: Congrats Peter. This community has benefitted from your contribution a lot. Keep doing.

Comment: Peter Kämpf's a true G in my books, I've read dozens of his answers and they're always spot on. He's got something against wing tip devices though.

Comment: The Karman line is around 328,000 feet; a ways more to go but no sign of leveling off yet https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsZXn.png

Comment: @RoryMcDonald That's because he knows in the absence of a span restriction they don't work as well as an extended wingtip. One of his 'questions' back in 2014 was an education on this, possibly in an attempt to counter marketers pushing winglets on everything. https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8556/is-a-winglet-better-than-an-equal-span-extension

Comment: That's quite an achievement, and I for one appreciate all his good answers.  I am a bit concerned about anyone with that kind of incredibly low ratio of questions to answers.  If you possess that much knowledge, you likely can come up some high quality interesting questions too.  One thing I've learned in life is that the more I learn, the less I know. :)